# Meaning of "建一个国内的飞机场，也能翻回去" and "美国不会对标建墙的"

Tags: translation, internet-slang

I'm confused by the statement "建一个国内的飞机场，也能翻回去" and "美国不会对标建墙的" in this short blog post from https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/fs2zbK1kGUJ1xirpDaEFNA. My translation would be "if you construct a domestic airport, it can be reverted" and "The United States will not build a wall against standards", which doesn't really make any more sense in the context of the whole blog post, which I've reproduced here:

> Tiktok还有被买走的机会。WeChat没没有人能接手的。
>
> 所以45天后，微信可能会停止对北美地区的服务。
>
> 后面怎么办？
>
> 国内和国外的朋友如何沟通？
>
> 1. Skype熟悉一下，这个好像中美之间都没有封掉。
> 2. 还有可以试试apple 的 FaceTime。这个也可以的的。这个在苹果手机上可以使用。
> 3. 还可以使用支付宝。现在支付宝还没有上单子，和国内沟通可以通过支付宝。没想到支付宝的社交梦想居然就这么实现了。
>    其实工具很多，比如钉钉也可以的。
> 4. 微信，QQ这些可能都会从 app store下掉。但是按照法规说法：只是下架，海外那边可以用安装包的方式装微信和qq，问题不会很大。 **美国不会对标建墙的。**
> 5. 可以通过翻墙的办法。**建一个国内的飞机场，也能翻回去。**
> 6. 如果有可能一家人在一起。
>    我一大半读者都是海外华人，如果真的禁止了，那么针对海外华人的公号基本上废了。所以得考虑其他的渠道。

My translation is as follows:

> TikTok still has a chance to be bought. No one can take over WeChat.
> So after 45 days, WeChat may stop serving North America.
> What to do later?
>
> How do friends in China and abroad communicate?
>
> 1. Get familiar with Skype. It seems that [communication] between China and the United States [using Skype] has not been sealed off.
> 2. You can also try Apple's FaceTime. This is also possible. This can be used on Apple phones.
> 3. You can also use Alipay. Now Alipay has not been added to the list, and communication with China can be through Alipay. I wouldn't have expected Alipay's social dreams to be realized in this way.
>    In fact, there are many tools, such as DingTalk, which can also be used.
> 4. WeChat and QQ may all be dropped from the app stores. However, according to the regulations: Just take it off the shelves, and install WeChat and QQ overseas by means of installation packages. The problem will not be big. **The United States will not build a wall against standards.**
> 5. You can circumvent the Great Firewall [or is this about circumventing American restrictions?]. **If you build a domestic airport, you can turn it back.**
> 6. If possible, be together as a family.
>    Most of my readers are overseas Chinese. If it is really banned, then the official account for overseas Chinese will basically be abandoned. So you have to consider other channels.

Comment: This written language sounds weird. Plus, Google has exactly 3 search results for 对标建墙, the Weibo article linked in this question, some webpage mirroring the Weibo article, and... this post.

Comment: 对标 means "is on par with", "is equivalent to". 对标建墙 sounds a little unnatural but is understood. It means "build a firewall on par (with GFW)".

Comment: FYI 飞机场 = set up your own SSR server

Comment: Technically speaking, 飞机场 or 机场 should be **proxy service (provider/hosts)**. There're a lot of proxy types. Popular ones include VPN, SS, SSR, Trojan, V2ray, etc. So "SSR server" or "VPN provider" cannot exactly translate 飞机场/机场 here.

Answer (score 1):

"墙" isn't a real wall here, but a "Internet wall". It made by governments, its target is forbiding the citizens explore some special sites on Internet. Chinese government has one, it forbids the people in China Mainland to connect to Google Search, Facebook, Twitter and some other sites. Some sites in this list are erotic, or about gambling, or Chinese government doesn't like it because there are always some anti-China things on those sites. The author of this article wants to say that **the US government won't build a wall like what China has.** If the US build it, the people in the US can't download WeChat or QQ or some other Chinese applications that forbid by the ban of the US government, and can only use some special ways to "climb over" it, such as using VPN.

"飞机场" is an argot, it means hosts in other areas. The people who use VPN connect to it to "climb over" the "Internet wall". So this sentence means "**build a host in China to climb over the ban to get some special things on the Internet from China**".

Comment: Perhaps: *firewall*?

Comment: Its official name isn't it. This name sounds like an anti-virus wall. Its official name is Great Firewall(防火长城)(Charles R. Smith named it), GFW for short.

Answer (score 1):

对标 means "to benchmark against" or "benchmarking". In this context, the definition of "benchmark" that we are using is "to use something as a standard in order to improve your own work, products, or processes" ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/benchmark)), or basically to copy/imitate.

飞机场 or 机场 here means a proxy provider for [Shadowsocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadowsocks), which is proxy software for getting around the [Great Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall), or something similar.

Thus,

- "美国不会对标建墙的" = "The United States will not copy [China] and build a Great Firewall."
- "建一个国内的飞机场" = "set up a Shadowsocks host in China"

With these definitions in mind, we can make the following revised translation (interspersed with some comments about the content of the article):

> TikTok still has a chance to be bought. No one can take over WeChat.
> So after 45 days, WeChat may stop serving North America.
> What to do later?
>
> How do friends in China and abroad communicate?
>
> 1. Get familiar with Skype. It seems that [communication] between China and the United States [using Skype] has not been sealed off.

Skype is not present in the App Store or in Chinese Android app markets. [Sapore di Cina writes](https://www.saporedicina.com/english/calling-from-china-skype-facetime/#call-from-china-1):

> However, if you try to download the Skype app on the iOS app market or one of the Android markets (Google Play is blocked) once you’re in China, you won’t find it. In addition, if you want to access the Skype webpage, you will be redirected to a Chinese webpage (skype.gmw.cn) where you will download a modified version of Skype that complies with Chinese regulations. Complying with Chinese regulations means that communications are redirected (and monitored) via a Skype partner in China.
>
> If you want to use Skype in China, I recommend that you download it to all of your devices before going, or if you’re already in China, that you download it with a VPN active directly from the official website and not from the Chinese version.
>
> The quality of calls and video calls with Skype from China is a bit lacking and it’s a good idea to use a good VPN to improve the quality, although it isn’t always enough.

> 2. You can also try Apple's FaceTime. This is also possible. This can be used on Apple phones.

New iPhone and iPad models sold for China markets from September 2013 onward do not have FaceTime Audio, but do have FaceTime Video. ([source](https://www.techinasia.com/apple-facetime-audio-disabled-china-iphone-ipad-models)). If you do have an iOS device with FaceTime however, it is the case that communication is not blocked.

> 3. You can also use Alipay. Now Alipay has not been added to the list, and communication with China can be through Alipay. I wouldn't have expected Alipay's social dreams to be realized in this way.
>    In fact, there are many tools, such as DingTalk, which can also be used.
> 4. WeChat and QQ may all be dropped from the app stores. However, according to the regulations: Just take it off the shelves, and install WeChat and QQ overseas by means of installation packages. The problem will not be big. **The United States will not copy [China] and build a Great Firewall.**
> 5. There are methods to circumvent the Great Firewall. **If you set up a Shadowsocks host in China, you can jump back over the Great Firewall.**
> 6. If possible, be together as a family.
>    Most of my readers are overseas Chinese. If it is really banned, then the official account for overseas Chinese will basically be abandoned. So you have to consider other channels.

Answer (score 0):

This article is about the current US executive order regarding TikTok and WeChat.  It warns that a user could lose their contacts if they use such 'soon banned' software, and promotes their own website.

It states that the USA will only take down the apps from the Apple store etc., but...

> 美国不会对标建墙的
> the USA will not build a firewall to against it [like in China]

So you can still install these apps via an .apk or .ipa file.

One of the options provided in 5. (namely Shadowsocks) is referred to as 飞机场 since the icon for Shadowsocks looks like an airplane.  FYI the tool is called 'SSR' or '小飞机'.